# undefined reference to wxGrid/wxPGProperty

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets

Работаю над проектом Cmake с использование библиотеки wxWidgets версии 3.0.2 и при сборке исполняемого файла на Linux выходит следующее:

```
undefined reference to `wxGrid::...`
undefined reference to `wxPGProperty::...`
и тогдалее по всем используемым функциям
```

И раньше вылезали подобные ошибки, но они устранились добавив в поиск модулей wxWidgeta - adv и propgrid. 
Проект состоит из пары библиотек и исполняемого файла, библиотеки собираются без проблем, хотя в них и не используются эти контролы.
CMakeList исполняемого файла:

```
project(Test)
set(HEADER  CMakeLists.txt 
            test.h 
            myMath.h)

set(SOURCE  test.cpp
            myMath.cpp) 

find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS core base adv propgrid )
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})


add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${HEADER} ${SOURCE} )

target_include_directories( ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE 
                            ${TEST_LIB1_DIR}
                            ${TEST_LIB2_DIR})

target_link_libraries(  ${PROJECT_NAME}
                        ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES}
                        Lib1
                        Lib2 )

set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES 
            RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG      ${TEST_DIR} 
            RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE    ${TEST_DIR} )
```

Я просто не могу понять, в чем может быть проблема (может в CMakeList). В инете нашёл схожие вопросы, но ответы на них сводились к наличию этих библиотек (adv и propgrid) на Linux'е. И да они есть в папке:

> wxWidgets-3.0.2/debug/lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема в моей невнимательности... Подключив новую библиотеку я забыл посмотреть подключенные модули wxWidgets в CMakeList

```
find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS core base adv propgrid )
```